# Click doesn't work on overlay

Tags: click, overlay

I put an overlay with the following css:

```
body.overlay:after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 z-index: 9998;
```

}

But then code that removes overlay class on body click, do not ignite, so this overlay do not go away.

Is there some restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

I made a JSFiddle and in the fiddle it works fine.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/sfueju4b/

HTML:

```
<body class="overlay">
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body.overlay:after {
     content: '';
     display: block;
     position: absolute;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
     background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
     z-index: 9998;
}
```

JS:

```
$('body').on('click', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('overlay');
    });
```